# mongodb 10gen repo invalid signature

Tags: apt, mongodb, gpg

I am trying to install mongodb on debian from 10gen repo. I have followed the official guide [HERE](http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian.html#install-debian-version-pinning) however i am stuck when trying to add the repo in apt.

The problem is that the signature is invalid. I add the gpg key using the command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

and then adding the repo in my sources.d file:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

However, when run apt-get update , i get the error that the signature is invalid.

> W: GPG error: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist Release: The following signatures were invalid: 492EAFE8CD016A07919F1D2B9ECBEC467F0CEB10
>   W: The repository 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist Release' is not signed.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

Anyone else having this problem?
Is indeed the signature wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The installation guide you are following is:

- a *copy* of an old version of the MongoDB documentation but not the official guide (which is hosted on `docs.mongodb.com`)
- referring to a historical version of MongoDB: v2.4 was released in 2013 and reached end of life in March, 2016

The public key, package names, and repo paths have changed since MongoDB 2.4.

You should instead be installing a current version of MongoDB using the official guide: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Debian](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/).

Also note: in August 2013 10gen (the MongoDB company) became [MongoDB, Inc](https://www.mongodb.com/press/10gen-announces-company-name-change-mongodb-inc).